# Synthetic canaries get no response from API Gateway test

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch-synthetics

I deploy the same code into 2 different lambdas that issue a `TestInvokeMethodCommand` to my Api Gateway. Both lambdas use the same IAM role, the same environment variables, everything the same configuration-wise. The only difference is that one of them is a regular lambda and the other one is deployed as CloudWatch Synthetic Canary, which means that there's a fancy AWS wrapper around it that handles CloudWatch things and my actual code is deployed as a lambda layer.

So basically it all goes down to the following

```js
 const result = await this.api.send(
            new TestInvokeMethodCommand({
                restApiId: this.apiId,
                resourceId: this.pathToResourceId(path),
                httpMethod,
                body: data?.body ? JSON.stringify(data.body) : undefined,
                headers: data?.headers,
            }),
        );

        this.logger.info({ result }, "WTF is going on?");
```

`this.api` in this case refers to a `APIGatewayClient` object.

Given all this is pretty much the same, how come the regular lambda gets a valid response with body, headers, latency etc, while the canary one only gets the `$metadata`?

From logs:

```
{
    "level": 30,
    "time": 1699979721850,
    "result": {
        "$metadata": {
            "httpStatusCode": 200,
            "requestId": "61aa93ca-fe8b-41ba-8d0c-418fab7c77f2",
            "attempts": 1,
            "totalRetryDelay": 0
        }
    },
    "msg": "WTF is going on?"
}
```

Does my response get obfuscated by the Synthetics layer? Why is my response missing?